# IntelliJ: Move to next typo

Tags: intellij-idea, spell-checking

IntelliJ IDEA has an inspection that checks for spelling. In the analysis overview, I can see how many spelling mistakes were found, e.g. `12 typos found`. In the code they are highlighted using a wavy green line.

However, I find it very hard to look manually for those wavy lines. Is there a **keyboard shortcut** or a **search function** which will automatically skip to the **next highlighted typo**?

Comment: F2 and Shift+F2 shortcuts will navigate you to the Next / Previous highlighted error. You need to configure the error navigation first to _Go to next problem_ (from the context menu of editor right side bar). See [help](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/navigating-to-next-previous-error.html) for details. Another option is to use double click(F4 shortcut) from the Inspection Results window to go to the source.

Comment: @Andrey ok, so there is no way to make this work without declaring typos to be errors (inspections -> spelling -> typo -> severity)? Because "Go to next problem" doesn't work with default green highlighting...

Comment: For the highlighting navigation to work with typos you need to change error navigation level to **Go to next problem** instead of default **Go to high priority problems** option, http://imageshack.us/a/img826/1082/c9ux.png

Comment: Thanks Andrey; I got confused. On OS X with Darcula, the menu items are not shown as _checkbox_ menus, so I didn't see which one was checked but thought that they are _action_ menus (nothing happening when I click on them). After "toggling" the item blindly, now F2 works. Please post as answer.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

<kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> shortcuts will navigate you to the Next / Previous highlighted error. You need to configure the error navigation first to **Go to next problem** instead of default **Go to high priority problems** option(from the context menu of editor right side bar):

[image]

See [help](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/navigating-to-next-previous-error.html) for details. Another option is to use double click (<kbd>F4</kbd> shortcut) from the Inspection Results window to go to the source.

Comment: This is the correct answer because the question asked for a keyboard shortcut. Those who would rather have a typo show up on the sidebar check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37002620/6243324

Answer (score 59):

#### IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3

If you want to fix all typos from the project, you can list all of them and iterate through them using double click (or <kbd>F4</kbd> to open the source):

- Analyze > Run Inspection by Name...

  [image: Analyze > Run Inspection by Name]
- Type "Typo"

  [image: Typo]

You will be able to see a list containing all typos grouped by file:

[image: Spelling]

Answer (score 6):

In `Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> General`, you can add an 'Error stripe mark' color to `Typo`.

Answer (score 4):

With the default settings of IntelliJ I find it difficult to spot the typos. So I do the following hack to spot and correct them once in a while.

1. Temporarily change inspection setting to show Typos as Errors. [image: Inspection settings]
2. IntelliJ then highlights the typos as Errors, making it much easier to spot them in the editor. I correct them and then revert the inspection setting changes. The changes can be kept permanently but I don't prefer that!