# How to find where is typo in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

In on of my classes Android Studio analysis shows that 1 typo found:

[image]

I know that the typo is marked with an underline, but it is too difficult to search all the code to find that. Is there any easier way to find typos?

Warnings and errors have yellow and red markers but I can't see any marker for typos.

Thanks

Comment: This answer may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/21419419/5183999

Comment: @nshmura Yes!! Worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: Missgh please confirm the dupe by clicking the banner on top